Mac/Linux command to get device name from IP address using mDNS
I need a command to get the hostname of a device on the network from the IP address, using multicast DNS. I used to use the dig command which worked perfectly on both macOS and Linux, and many websites suggest using this (dig -x $IP @224.0.0.251 -p 5353 +short +time=1), but I noticed that it doesn't work anymore on the newest versions. I found this Gitlab issue online which explains that something was changed on dig, and it wasn't intended to be used for mDNS anyways.
On Linux, I found that you can use avahi-resolve-address which does exactly what I need. The problem is that avahi is not available for macOS. Also I've found some Mac-specific commands (see this link) which get the IP address from the hostname, but that's the opposite of what I am looking for.
So are there any commands which will work on macOS to get the mDNS name from the IP address?

Edit: I've found out from this link that dig has its own built-in resolver code, and also it says in the man page that it "does not use the host name and address resolution or
the DNS query routing mechanisms used by other processes running on Mac
OS X." So that might explain why dns-sd isn't working for getting the hostname from the IP address. I'm still not sure if there are any ways to do this with other commands, without replicating the code in dig.

dns-sd is the MacOS command for mDNS lookups, although it's a bit inconvenient for reverse lookups.
For example, if the IP you want to look up is 10.11.12.13:
dns-sd -q 13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa ptr

But some devices might not respond to reverse mDNS queries. In that case, you can try checking the local (m)DNS cache:
dscacheutil -q host -a ip_address 10.11.12.13

If the host you wish to look up has sent out any mDNS multicast responses while your local host has been able to receive them, this should reveal the name associated with the IP address. Unfortunately this command is not specific to mDNS, but will return any cached regular DNS results too if they match the IP address.

The command you gave didn't work for me, even when I put the IP address backwards. It always says "No Such Record."

Hi. Thanks for suggesting another command to try, but the second command isn't working for me either (it does not output anything). Did you test these commands yourself, and if did they work for you?

Can you look at my comment please? @telcoM

I tried them, and as far as I could determine, they worked for me. However I noticed that not all devices seem to respond to reverse mDNS queries, and will trust that the asker's cache will resolve those using the data from cached regular (forward) mDNS records instead. It seems to me Linux mDNS tools handle such cases better than macOS command line mDNS tools.

Does dig use reverse queries (when used with the command in the top of the page)? Because if so it is working fine for reverse queries-- all of the devices I've tested are responding to the queries, whereas dns-sd is not working. And dig isn't specifically a Linux tool but is on Mac, too. I think the avahi-resolve-address command might be using a cache, though.
